# How To Display Multiple Columns In Combo Box

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, combobox

On list "ListPurchInv" I have several columns - in J column, is remaining amount. In D column in document no. I want to AddItem into ComboBox from column D, must fulfill condition, that remaining amount is not 0.

Now I can visible only remaining amount.

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()


    Me.Label4.Visible = Me.CheckBox1
    Me.cb_SelInvToPay.Visible = Me.CheckBox1

    Dim c As Range

    With Worksheets("ListPurchInv")
        For Each c In .Range("K2", .Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If c.Value <> 0 Then cb_SelInvToPay.AddItem c.Value
        Next c
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How can you assign a `CheckBox` to the `Visible` property of a `Label`? The `.Visible` property is a Boolean. Default properties of controls have not been in use for quite a while.

Comment: I think you want `Me.CheckBox1.Checked` which is a Boolean.